# What's the best way to get the "Rampage!" achievement?

Tags: achievements, counter-strike-global-offensive

Taken from the CS:GO Wiki:

> [image: something]
>       **Rampage!**
>       Win an Arms Race match without dying.

As it currently stands, this achievement is almost unbeatable for me to get. By the time I get to be about mid tier (rifles and snipers), I seem to get killed at that point.

I'd also like to mention the fact that I'm playing with other people.  Even so, it's a fairly difficult achievement, and I'd like to try and get it.

What can I do to get this achievement legitly?  I've tried playing with easy bots to get it; even so, it's painfully hard, especially when you get down to the gold knife level.  Is there any tricks, console commands, possibly guides to actually getting this achivement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest playing easy bots and being more sneaky than usual. I got this achievement on my 2nd try versus easy bots on the Baggage level. First off, I stuck to the outside of the map (right side from CT spawn ramp) and peaked bots to kill them and retreated when necessary. Definitely do not go running around the middle of the map, try not to get shot even once because your health needs to last the entire match.

It is very possible to go a long while without getting shot once versus easy bots. My first try I had gotten shot once for 13 damage all the way until nearly the end when some bot got lucky and killed me.

The last kill with the knife was pretty tricky... The bots all had shotguns at that point and it was difficult to get close enough to kill one without getting shot. I would recommend going down the ramp from CT maybe into the lower baggage area and try to find one that isn't looking. Be **Very** sneaky when trying to get the final knife kill, the knife kill may take a few tries.

If you wanna do this versus humans you're just going to have to be **VERY** good and get lucky by playing against some weaker opponents. I really think that against humans this is nearly impossible. Stick to easy bots. (If you want to cheese it, bots_knives_only will probably get you an easy win, but you said you wanted it legitimately)

Comment: TIL you could get achievements playing offline with bots. Only 500+ hrs spent ...

Comment: Thanks spent ages on various maps, Safehouse being my fave and know all the nooks and crannies but baggage was the winner - first time! right hand side ramp camping style then knife kill was so lucky went down ramp and one stood facing away!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend having only 1 enemy and 2 allied bots; (bot_kick )

With this setup your allied bots will find and distract the enemy, possibly lowering his health, while you go in for the actual kill.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Easiest and quickest way to get Rampage with no cheats is on Safehouse. Seriously, with a good line up of weapons, it's easy for me to finish Safehouse with very few deaths. So enough tries, you'll get it. A successful attempt will only take between 5-10 minutes.

Join Terrorist side and stand in the doorway to the bathroom at the top of the stairs. You get a great vantage point looking down the stairs at the front door. At that range, even short shotguns will not be a problem when it comes to just slaughtering easy bots as they come through the front door or try to go up the stairs. You don't have to venture from that spot really. You do have to keep an eye on the doorway to the Bombsite room though.  If you get into trouble, just pull back into the bathroom and chill for a bit.

When it comes time for that knife kill, just wait in that bathroom for someone to come upstairs, preferably when some of your teammates are there to distract them, run out and knife 'em.

If that's not a good enough explanation, here's a video:

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is head up to the top level and wait in the left hand side windows. They stop to aim, and you can lay them all down until the knife round where you wait for them to be busy with an ally and use the heavy knife attack on their back.
Only use this on the shoots map!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to start up a game offline with easy bots on baggage and join Terrorist as it is easier to get the achievement with. Go to the right when the round starts and camp up that hallway and just shoot bots as they come over. When you get to the two shotguns in a row pop down to the lowest level without taking damage and just be patient till you get them. As soon as you do go back to the spot I mentioned earlier. You will need about 60 HP left when you get to the knife level to have a chance at getting it. If you have less than that it is very unlikely you will get it. Just camp in the basement again and wait for an enemy bot to drop down and just knife the heck out of them. You will need to be pretty good with your aim and be careful enough not to take any damage. (Will take around 20 attempts most likely.)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this on Lake without any cheats. Be skillful enough and it's easy. I'm totally not very good and I could do this.

First try and get a good lineup of accurate weapons: CT SMGs (p90, mp7, mp9), the two scoped rifles, the two long shotguns, the m249 machine gun, and one or two of the heavy pistols.

At the start head to the house upstairs bedroom level and you can safely snipe off easy bots out in the field (or other windows also if you can), granted you snipe smart (keep moving, be patient, don't repeek, know when you're burnt). This is easier to do on CT team; CT spawn is too close to the house and CT tends to raid the house more. For when the enemy starts raiding the house, set a "door trap": The door to that upstairs bedroom, open it so it swings out. Do this and a bot will have to close the door before they can open it. You'll hear the door close and you can either hang back until they go away or prepare to shoot as they come through and get another kill. Either way, set the door trap back before going back to sniping. You can also hide in the bathroom for as long as you want as long as you don't snipe from there. You can take a break, go to the bathroom IRL, or wait for the enemy team to graduate to shotguns or pistols to make them easier to shoot and knife.

When you get to shotguns yourself: if you don't want to wait for someone to get close enough to the house, go to the basement and try to lure someone through that door facing T-spawn (open the door, fire out, then close door and wait)  Or do what I do, peek out and if it's safe, look for a enemy facing away that's close enough, then run out quickly and knife them in the back since a knife kill bumps you up a level automatically. You're going to have to do this to get that final knife kill. And pistols: be patient, take your time, wait for the best opportunity, and concentrate on getting that headshot.

There's other places to snipe: Back of the house underneath the diving board, I find Bombsite level floor makes it easy to get head shots, there's even a way to get to the roof of the house to snipe (Top upstairs level, back of the house side facing CT spawn, you can crawl out the window onto the roof) but the roof leaves you exposed, so the best place is that upstairs bedroom.

Comment: This needs some paragraph breaks.  It's really hard to read right now.

Comment: lol I just added them. Better?

Answer (score -2):

Start a game with easy bots.

Type in the console

```
sv_cheats 1
```

and than

```
bot_knives_only
```

Now the bots should only use the knife in the next round. 
Just try to survive the first round where they still using their guns.

Comment: But if you use sv_cheats 1, doesn't the game prevent you from getting achievements?

Comment: Turning sv_cheats on immediately blocks all achievements.

Answer (score -4):

If you just want to get the achievement by any means, ask a few friends to join you in an empty server and ask them to stand still while you go "Rampage". But this will take away the fun and the work from the achievements. It takes their only meaning from the game.

Comment: Exactly why I asked how can I do this legitimately, without having to call in extra help or rely on friends to get it?

Comment: Well without a certain setup, i think that you have to try and try since there is no way to get it other than legitimate (i.e. using cheats) on random servers. I think you need a bit of luck and a lot of skill. Maybe try to stay near or in the base at all times which might be a little safer.